# Is there an unemployment issue in the movie "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the movie, *Avengers: Endgame*, the Snap made by

> Professor Hulk brings back 3.5 billion people to Earth. Since all these people have been gone for 5 years,

does this mean that the world's unemployment rate is now at

> 50%, or would Professor Hulk's snap have also restored the jobs these people had before the Snap by Thanos?

Comment: The snap can restore jobs? Your assumption is flawed.

Comment: @Shreedhar, I don't know if it did or not. My guess is that it did not restore the peoples' jobs so the unemployment rate is at 50%.

Comment: Well the people are still old and sick, need their hair cut and need food. So most people would have jobs pretty fast.

Comment: actually, with no economie to produce all the food, housing and medical needs, most of those people are going to be dead again soon

Comment: @HRIATEXP *au contraire*. The population doubled in an instant so every need and requirement on the planet doubled. Thus it created a lot of opportunities and jobs, not otherwise

Comment: Jobs are an abstract thing, you can't turn them to dust with the infinity gauntlet.

Comment: @Christian At least the number of animals also doubled, but it will be bad times for vegetarians.

Comment: @Shreedhar:  Maybe it if can restore Jobs, Apple will stop trying to sell overpriced uninnovative products.   And monitor mounts for $999.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pure speculation, but there'll be a reasonable amount of economic and personal chaos, and it sets up some interesting aspects which can be explored in future films/shows, including:

- Jobs which were eliminated due to a suddenly fallen population being needed again.
- People who've had their estates distributed according to their will (as they were dead), and are now penniless.
- Relationships where people moved on, and now you've got one party who lived through 5 years of loss, grief and recovery, and another who feels as if nothing happened at all.
- Dealing with the previously burgeoning population, with infrastructure which was starting to crumble.
- Family units dealing with children of massively altered ages (little sister is now big sister, etc.).
- Countries where power structures were devastated, compared to ones which "got off lightly"

There are a *lot* of potential storylines opened up from the end of the film. And that's not even counting the ones that the time travel open up ("Why, hello again, Loki!").

Comment: There are on-screen news headlines and the like which talk about "missing" and "vanished".  I do not recall anything on-screen where people are taken to be _dead_, however; and 5 years is too short for _in absentia_ in many jurisdictions.

Comment: @JdeBP I see no reason why they would think they would come back. In any case, if someone goes missing for 5 years they are typically presumed to be dead.

Comment: Not in many jurisdictions, as I just said.

Answer (score 0):

The world is in a terrible state with whole districts falling into disrepair as we see when Ant-Man is walking down Cassie's street. As such it needs rebuilding and repairing so there would be countless jobs on offer to sort that out.

And to be honest in the grand scheme of things will these people even care, at least initially? They were dead and now they are not, reunions are to be had and the world rebuilt. People aren't going to care initially whether or not they have a job, they would just be glad to be back once they find out what happened.

> or would Professor Hulk's snap have also restored the jobs these people had before the Snap by Thanos?

No, the snap by Professor Hulk only brings back the dusted and changes nothing else, or at least that is what he tried to do. Tony makes it very clear that all they were doing was bringing people back and Professor Hulk agrees with him.

This is made clear with what we see happening with nothing else in the world changing, the bird coming back and Peter's comments along the lines of "I fell asleep and when I woke up you'd gone" (not correct but the sentiment is the same).

---

In fact the Russo brothers actually answered a related questionin an interview from [this Chinese source](https://ent.qq.com/a/20190429/007983.htm). As the original article is in Chinese I am getting the quotes from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bj0it4/joe_russos_qa_about_the_plot_of_avengers_endgame/), although I think all that's happened is that the user ran it through Google Translate.

> Q: What about those people who got dusted? What did those five years mean to them? Why didn't they grow older when undusted?
>
> A: Yes, those people whom was lucky to survive the snap are 5 years older than the people who just got back. The reason Spider Man saw his friend again in high school at the end was simply because his friends was unfortunately also dusted like Spider Man was. Of course, there are people in his grade whom didn't die and they are probably already in colleges by now. **To those dusted people, they had no conscious in these past 5 years. They didn't know what happened. It's as if they had just woke up from a long sleep.** The only one who was aware about how many years has passed was Doctor Strange, because he has already seen that when he was time mediating on Titan. Parker's reunion with Ned was a touching moment. **There are also people whom indeed moved on but suddenly was reunited with their lost ones. Yeah it's kind a complicated world now.**